# For decades, the logo had been white lettering on a blue square, with a classic feel

Tags: parts-of-speech

> For decades, the logo had been white lettering on a blue square, with a classic feel.

What are the parts of speech of 'white' and 'lettering'?

Is this a progressive sentence?

Comment: Did you look up "lettering" in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, of course. But I wanted to hear an answer to be sure of the meaning.

Comment: Please indicate that in your questions or they will remain closed for lack of research. We're volunteers answering your questions. Respect our time and effort by doing as much work as you can to answer the question yourself first, *and show us what work you've done and what you're still unsure about*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[lettering](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lettering) in this context is a noun meaning "letters used in an inscription" (according to Merriam-Webster) or letters used in other designs.

"white" is an adjective modifying the noun.

So the logo included text written in white letters.